# How to deal with non standard date formats in SQL (mySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and learning at the moment. I am using MySQL installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                                   availability date NOT NULL);
```

I want to insert the following record in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, `availability`) 
VALUES ('Title 1', last Wednesday);
```

when executing I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'Wednesday)'

I understand that this format ('last Wednesday', 'next week',..) is not a standard date format. I wanted to know if it is possible to create user-defined types in MySQL to be able to process these bespoke date records.

So far what I have found on the web deals with dates that still contain more or less a standard date format, not as bespoke as those mentioned above (use cast, parse,..).

Comment: You can have a user defined function with logic to convert these text into proper date value and the proper date value to INSERT

Answer (score 2):

What you have are functions like `NOW()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and `CURRENT_DATE()`. For anything else like `LAST_WEDNESDAY()` you can write your own [stored functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

```
create function last_wednesday() returns date no sql
  return current_date() - interval (weekday(current_date()) + 4)%7+1 day;
```

Or use the same expression inline in your queries.

#### Update

As asked by Strawberry - Here is something "more scalable":

```
create function human_to_date(str text, date date) returns date no sql
  return case
    when str = 'last monday'    then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-0)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last tuesday'   then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-1)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last wednesday' then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-2)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last thursday'  then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-3)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last friday'    then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-4)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last saturday'  then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-5)%7+1 day
    when str = 'last sunday'    then date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-6)%7+1 day
  end
;
```

Use it as

```
select human_to_date('last wednesday', now())
```

or for any date as reference

```
select human_to_date('last sunday', '2019-10-01')
```

This will return the last sunday in this month (sept. 2019)

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9236Qb4bxE6ieNApbHuKW/0)

I've tried to remove code duplication, but ended with this:

```
delimiter //
create function human_to_date(str text, date date) returns date no sql
begin
  declare day_of_week int default null;
  if str rlike '^last (monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)$' then
    set day_of_week = case substring_index(str, ' ', -1)
      when 'monday'    then 0
      when 'tuesday'   then 1
      when 'wednesday' then 2
      when 'thursday'  then 3
      when 'friday'    then 4
      when 'saturday'  then 5
      when 'sunday'    then 6
    end;
    return date - interval (weekday(date) + 6-day_of_week)%7+1 day;
  end if;
  return null;
end //
delimiter ;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/crcc7d6jLwn4XHLA2Q6SHU/0)

Comment: Nice...I couldn't figure out how to get mod working on this one.

Comment: @Strawberry In what terms? Something like `human_to_date('last sunday')`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that

Comment: @Strawberry You knew, that it's going to ugly. Admit it! ;-)

Comment: Frankly, I didn't think you'd take the bait ;-)

Comment: It was really helpful. Going to apply that to more specific cases which I need. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to dates, the natural language capabilities of some application languages is so good that I'd be tempted to handle the logic there instead.

For instance, here's some PHP:

```
<?php

echo(date(DATE_RFC850,strtotime( date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month')).' last wednesday')));

?>
```

Today is Thursday 26th September. This echoes Wednesday, 25-Sep-19 00:00:00 BST

Answer (score 0):

When storing in a db, you need information that make sense. a value "last Wednesday" for a product, does not give any reasonable availability info. For example, last Wednesday from which date? If someone asks for all available products on last Wednesday but 2 months later than today, what will a query looking for "last Wednesday" return? Definitely invalid results. So, if you want to store a date, then use a date/datetime datatype. You can add any custom description you want by using an additional column with varchar datatype, but i wouldn't use this as a primary info source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to insert last Wednesday's date into your table:

```
INSERT INTO product(name, availability)
SELECT
    'Title 1',
    CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) >= 2
         THEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 2 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()), CURDATE())
         ELSE TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 2 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 7, CURDATE()) END;
```

Notes: It would be hard to pull this off using a select with a `VALUES` clause, unless perhaps we define a UDF, so I am using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  The `CASE` expression checks if the current date is a Wednesday (2) through Sunday (6).  If so, then we offset the current date by the difference, to shift it back to Wednesday.  Similar logic applies for Monday (0) and Tuesday (1).

Comment: Nice - not quite what was asked for though

Comment: @Strawberry I recall last Wednesday quite clearly.  I spent the evening answering SQL questions on Stack Overflow.